# Partially applied function as object

Tags: scala, currying

Let

```
def f(i:Int)(j:Int) = i + j
```

and so

```
f(1) _
Int => Int = <function1>
```

However,

```
val f: (Int)(Int) => Int = (a:Int)(b:Int) => a + b  // wrong
```

namely, `error: ';' expected but '(' found.` How to declare `val f` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
scala> val f: Int => Int => Int = a => b => a + b
f: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>

scala> f(1)
res7: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> f(1)(2)
res8: Int = 3
```

Comment: Yes, exactly; it looks quite much like Haskell :) Thanks!